# belongs_to and has_many to the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-3

I am wondering whether there is a way to do this with rails or not. Basically I have a user model and an event model. Event is created by a user and I want to have a foreign key (user_id) in the event model that indicates who created the event. Additionally, event can have many users who attend it so the event model becomes something like

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :users, :through => :guests #suppose i have the guest model
```

and the user model looks something like

```
has_many :events, :through => :guests
```

I have not tried this association yet but I want to be able to say

```
e = Event.find(1)
e.creator #returns the user who created this event
```

instead of

```
e.user
```

is there a way for me to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply pass some options to `belongs_to`:

```
belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user_id"
```

This specifies that the `creator` method will  be a `User` object, referencing the `user_id` field.

Comment: wait a seconds, what would I put on the user model though? if I want to say user.created_events which returns the events that the user has created?

Comment: @denniss You can do this, but not with a `has_many :through`.

Comment: how would I do it. or may be can you refer me to an article or tutorial that does this?

Comment: @denniss There is no way to do it via a `has_many :through`. If you can sacrifice the `:through`, then you can use `has_many :created_events, :class_name => "Event"`

Comment: @JacobRelkin How did you determine that you cannot mix a has_many :through and a belongs_to to the same table? Is it documented somewhere or did you just figure it out?