# Rails :through associations getting error, couldn't find association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have 3 models,

Users, Location, Items

Location would only have 1 user, but User has many items or locations. and Items belongs to user or location.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many items, through: :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations
  has_many :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Could not find the association :users in model Location
```

I know, I can add `has_many :users` in Location model, but location is supposed to only have 1 user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be it:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
  has_many items, through: :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  has_many :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

To make more sense, read it this way:

`Location` `has_one` `user`

`User` `belongs_to` `location`

`User` `has_many` `items`

`Item` `belongs_to` `user`

`Location` `has_many` `items`, `through: :user`

*Essentially you are delegating a model relationship to another model.* *So instead of having to call `location.user.items` you can just do `location.items`.*

Comment: But what if user has many locations? Can I have belongs_to and has_many locations?

Comment: I think so, you can have both `belongs_to location` and `has_many locations` in the User model. Give it a shot and let me know!
To do so, this might help and give you some idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516416/belongs-to-and-has-many-to-the-same-model

Comment: I just go this error... `ERROR:  column users.location_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."location_id" = $1 ...` Does that mean, I need to add a `location_id` to user table? If so, I think this is wrong association then because, if user has multiple locations, then how would the `user` table store multiple `location_id`? Just trying to figure out how this association should work... I think I'm almost there

Comment: Yes, thats correct. Add `location_id` to the `users` table.

Comment: That means this allows for only 1 location that user can have right? How do make it so user can have multiple locations? Or am I thinking this wrong?

Comment: if you want `user has_many locations` then you have to have:  `location belongs_to user`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87731/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-hellomello).

Answer (score 1):

because you say ...

> I know, I can add has_many :users in Location model, but location is supposed to only have 1 user.

Instead of `has_many :users` you could do this

```
has_one :user
```